# Inserting machine name string in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, database, cognos

I have a few machine running databases and the database tables names have the machine name included in them.

Say `machine1`, `machine2`, `machineN` are the machine names. The database names tables are like `<machineName>_cm.dbo.TableName` and an example would be `machine1_cm.dbo.cmobjects`.

How can I insert a variable that would pick up the machine name and append the `_cm.dbo.TableName` to it as part of a SQL query that I need to run on all these machines?

```sql
SELECT columnName1, columnName2, columnName3 
FROM machine1_cm.dbo.DMOBJNAMES ...
```

I was thinking something like the following would work but it's not:

```sql
SELECT columnName1, columnName2, columnName3 
FROM @@servername+_cm.dbo.MYOBJNAMES;
```

or

```sql
SELECT columnName1, columnName2, columnName3 
FROM SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName' _cm..dbo.MYOBJNAMES;
```

Comment: Check sp_executesql.

Comment: You have to use dynamic sql.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic SQL.

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '
SELECT columnName1, columnName2, columnName3 
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName') AS sysname) + '_cm') + '.dbo.MYOBJNAMES;
';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Don't forget to parameterize where possible, you can pass parameters to `sp_executesql`

Alternatively you can execute the whole batch in the context of that database

```sql
DECLARE @proc nvarchar(1000) =
    QUOTENAME(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName') AS sysname) + '_cm')
    + '.sys.sp_executesql';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '
SELECT columnName1, columnName2, columnName3 
FROM dbo.MYOBJNAMES;
';

EXEC @proc @sql;
```